# Extreme Speed Baking

Tags: baking

What techniques/recipes exist that are utilized specifically to considerably reduce baking time (to between 1 and 2 minutes) of, say, chocolate chip cookies - without perceptibly diverging from the  taste, texture and shape/size/weight, of a typical such cookie?

More generally, I'm asking is there a way to make the baking time of common pastries 2x, 3x, 4x, 5x, etc. times faster…successfully ?

Cheers!

Comment: Baking cookies in 2 minutes? Is this actually a serious question? Even the packaged cookie dough doesn't bake that fast. I'm pretty sure the only answer to "how can I have [any food] ready in 2 minutes or less?" is "buy it pre-made".

Comment: Aaronut, yes, serious. I'm only referring to baking time not any pre-prep or cooling time.

Comment: Double your oven temperature; the cookies will bake twice as fast.

Answer (score 8):

Consider that commercial industrial bakeries would be highly motivated to reduce baking time if it was feasible, at least in a money saving manner.

And yet the equipment for continuous process baking uses approximately the same temperatures and times used at home, just with continuous rather than batch oriented equipment, and with a higher degree of precision and ability to repeat consistently.

One therefore concludes that the traditionally known times are at least approximately optimal in terms of outcome and energy (or at least cost).

---

In some sense, cookies (historically, the word comes from a term for "little cake") *are* your speed baking answer.  They bake in 12-18 minutes typically, compared to full sized cakes which bake in a time on the order of an hour.

By reducing the size of the food item, the time to cook through is reduced.

Very small cookies (thumbnail sized) can bake through in 5-8 minutes or so, but are terribly tedious and difficult to portion out accurately enough to get consistently good results at home.

Comment: Exactly. Most efficiency improvements in commercial bakeries focus on reducing mixing and prep times. Cooking times are considered a given.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of timing in Baking is dependent on heat transfer through the material and governed by the laws of thermodynamics.  The outer layers of the cookie in a way act as 'slow insulators' to delay the cooking of the interior.  Beside that, the chemical action of the baking powder is fast enough to act within seconds so no problem there.

With traditional methods, you can't improve the heat-transfer inside the cookie (unless you run copper strips or other heat conducting materials which would moot the point).

However, since you're into extreme cooking, you *may* be able to do it in the microwave.  Most microwaves have weird hotspots that are not easy to find and if you can manage them, I don't see why you couldn't bake a cookie the MW in 30 seconds or something.

Some other baked goods (cheetos, cheese puffs, and cheerios) are baked at very high speeds.  I believe cheerios are in sub-seconds (come out of a nozzle in a hot oven, get clipped, and fall).

Comment: So, introduce a neutral and safe ingredient (or more) that alter heat conductivity of the dough, raise baking temperatures, and reduce baking time?

Comment: unfortunately most edible stuff's heat conductivity isn't going to be that much better and cookies made out of metal aren't as addictive.  The cheese-puffs work because they're so light and fairly small in the beginning.  If you make your cookies small enough and have a steam oven, perhaps. The Microwave can deliver heat in a non-conductive way, which is why I suggested it might work better in this case.  While Vongerichten's the molten chocolate cake was an accident of increasing temperature and reducing time, you can't always expect good results that way ;)

Comment: Actually cheese puffs are produced under extreme pressure, and then they literally explode (in a manner similar to popcorn) when the steam expands as they exit the pressure.  The starches also gelatinize.  It is a very specialized process.